# Unable to insert records to DynamoDB from the command line

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have tried all possible way of working with dynamodb cli and still not able to insert in one simple table.

Command :

`aws dynamodb put-item --table-name my_table --item '{"id":{"S":"1"}}' --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

Error parsing parameter '--item': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:
'{id:{S:1}}'
^

Comment: locally hosted dynamo only gives a subset of features and is only meant for minor development purposes when you really can't be connected to the internet. I'm not surprised if the API the local version exposes and the cli are out of sync

Answer (score 0):

The item data can be saved as JSON file and then execute the command providing the file path.

**Example:-**

If you are in windows, navigate to the file path (i.e. put_item.json) using `cd` command and execute the below command.

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name table-name --item file://put_item.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

**Update:-**

If you don't want to use the JSON file, you can execute the command from [GIT BASH CLI](https://git-for-windows.github.io/). It should work.

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name my-table-name --item '{"id":{"S":"1"}}' --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

**From windows command prompt:-**

In windows command prompt, please **escape the double quotes with another double quotes** to form the correct JSON. It should work.

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name my-table-name --item "{""id"":{""S"":""1""}}" --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```